# How to paste output of each for loop as a new column in bash

Tags: bash

I want to paste each output of for loop, which is 47232 lines from one ID header to another, as new columns.

sample_names.txt:

```
BER1_EW
BER2_EW
BER3_EW
```

pvalues_table.txt:

```
ID_REF  VALUE   Detection_Pval_BER1_M
ILMN_1762337    6.471541272 0.83377
ILMN_2055271    6.656830829 0.01039
ILMN_1736007    6.608331034 0.03117
ILMN_2383229    6.422505498 0.98571
ILMN_1806310    6.485137674 0.75455
ILMN_1779670    6.461162622 0.8961
ILMN_1653355    6.485137674 0.75065
ID_REF  VALUE   Detection_Pval_BER1_EW
ILMN_1762337    6.520879646 0.40909
ILMN_2055271    6.625196689 0.01688
ILMN_1736007    6.508413634 0.52078
ILMN_2383229    6.534650524 0.30779
ILMN_1806310    6.57025659  0.11429
ILMN_1779670    6.516806214 0.45714
ILMN_1653355    6.527763921 0.36364
ID_REF  VALUE   Detection_Pval_BER2_EW
ILMN_1762337    6.502887717 0.58571
ILMN_2055271    6.668240334 0.01039
ILMN_1736007    6.509376312 0.53117
ILMN_2383229    6.485472189 0.72857
ILMN_1806310    6.446963181 0.92987
ILMN_1779670    6.555103846 0.20519
ILMN_1653355    6.476129698 0.79221
ID_REF  VALUE   Detection_Pval_BER3_EW
ILMN_1762337    6.489766129 0.69481
ILMN_2055271    6.598866345 0.04805
ILMN_1736007    6.505102091 0.55714
ILMN_2383229    6.522552494 0.41039
ILMN_1806310    6.544708753 0.26104
ILMN_1779670    6.534736264 0.32468
ILMN_1653355    6.512696201 0.50909
```

```
cat sample_names.txt| while read sample
do grep -A 47231 Detection_Pval_$sample pvalues_table.txt; done > new_pvaltable.txt
```

new_pvaltable.txt:

```
ID_REF  VALUE   Detection_Pval_BER1_EW
ILMN_1762337    6.520879646 0.40909
ILMN_2055271    6.625196689 0.01688
ILMN_1736007    6.508413634 0.52078
ILMN_2383229    6.534650524 0.30779
ILMN_1806310    6.57025659  0.11429
ILMN_1779670    6.516806214 0.45714
ILMN_1653355    6.527763921 0.36364
ID_REF  VALUE   Detection_Pval_BER2_EW
ILMN_1762337    6.502887717 0.58571
ILMN_2055271    6.668240334 0.01039
ILMN_1736007    6.509376312 0.53117
ILMN_2383229    6.485472189 0.72857
ILMN_1806310    6.446963181 0.92987
ILMN_1779670    6.555103846 0.20519
ILMN_1653355    6.476129698 0.79221
ID_REF  VALUE   Detection_Pval_BER3_EW
ILMN_1762337    6.489766129 0.69481
ILMN_2055271    6.598866345 0.04805
ILMN_1736007    6.505102091 0.55714
ILMN_2383229    6.522552494 0.41039
ILMN_1806310    6.544708753 0.26104
ILMN_1779670    6.534736264 0.32468
ILMN_1653355    6.512696201 0.50909
```

Specifications: Each ID_REF is the same for all samples. Sample names are not sorted, there are different names also- in a format like [A-Z]*[1-9]*_EW.

In the  `new_pvaltable.txt`, I want to have each sample(a sample is ID header+ 7 lines) written to a new column. Right now each sample is written below each other.

In original file, I have 2m lines in `new_pvaltable.txt`. If I can write each sample to a new column, I will have 47232 lines and 3*48 columns. Again, 48 is for sample size and each has 3 columns.

The code I put here only subsets the initial file, it does not give me the format I need.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please post samples of output too in your question to make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Output is the new_pvaltable.txt file from which I post a subset. I am making the question more clear now. thanks.

Comment: Ok, could you please post sample of input because I believe it could be done in a single command like awk or perl rather than using for loop, kindly do add input for making it more clear.

Comment: So, input is in the format same as output, but it is a larger file. I want to subset input and change the format . I restated my question, hope it is clear now.

Comment: Could you please do add small sample of Input_file(in your question) then we could better understand this question.

Comment: @kikibobo : At least to me, I don't understand what you are going to do, and how the piece of code you have posted is supposed to achieve the goal. I suggest that you provide as an example a `sample_names.txt` and a `pvalues_table.txt` and what you expect to be inside `new_pvaltable.txt`. Are you aware that you are creating a separate process for each line in `sample_names.txt`? Depending on the size of this file, this could be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @user1934428 I edited the question with examples from all files. Hope it is understandable now. Also, I am not aware of creating separate processes, I appreciate if you explain the problem there and if you can help solve it. thanks.

Comment: @kikibobo : Don't post **examples from** each files, but **complete** files; of course small enought that it is feasible to reproduce the case. Among other things, I don' understand from your posting, what makes the line _ILMN_1762337    6.502887717 0.58571_  appear in `new_pvaltable.txt`.

Comment: @user1934428 I edited again and put reproducible cases.

Comment: The examples are already quite good, but you need to be more precise in your specification: So, your pvalues_table.txt contains several sections with names ending in, i.e., BER1_EW. Are these sections sorted by name? Can one section occur more than once? Can we assume them to be sorted (which would make the task easier)? You need to define the format and the properties of your files. An example is excellent for illustration, but it is not a specification.

Comment: @user1934428 Got it. Sections are not sorted, there are non-BER names also. I am adding some specifications.